# Boto3 assume role with IAM user credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk

How can one assume an IAM role using IAM user credential?

```
import boto3

sts_client = boto3.client(
      'sts',
      aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    )
)

sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=some-role, RoleSessionName='boto3_client')
```

The above code for some reason produces:

```
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I have tested the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` using `aws sts assume-role` and I can indeed assume that role using the CLI. What am I doing wrong?

If it makes any difference, the IAM user is in the Chinese partition of AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` (not even `AWS_REGION`) environment variable fixes it.

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` is not mentioned anywhere in boto3 documentation. And turns out you can pass the region to `boto3.client()` with `region_name` argument. Odd name (`aws_region` would be a more consistent choice), and this is not mentioned in the documention either. I hope this helps someone out someday.